npm error while creating React app using npx create-react-app
[enter image descriptionenter image description here here](https://i.sstatic.net/AJmLnAr8.png)
Hey ! I am learning react, I was creating react folder from CMD (npx create-react-app firstreactapp). It gives an error of npm, and I also created the npm folder later, but even after creating the folder it gives an error. After giving the error, I tried (npm start) and it still gives an error. What should I do?

You can try these steps

Verify Node.js and npm are installed and up-to-date using node -v and npm -v, updating them if needed.
Clear the npm cache with npm cache clean --force to remove potential corruption.
Delete the partially created project folder (firstreactapp) and ensure no conflicting files remain.
Run npx create-react-app firstreactapp again to create the project.
If the error persists, navigate to the project folder using cd firstreactapp and install the missing dependency with npm install web-vitals.
Start the React development server using npm start.
If issues still occur, delete any global create-react-app installation using npm uninstall -g create-react-app, and retry with npx create-react-app firstreactapp.
For persistent errors, check for proxy or network restrictions and reset npm configurations using npm config delete proxy and npm config delete https-proxy.

